# How to write integer values to file without quotes and parentheses

Tags: python, csv

I have a dictionary with keys as a tuple, I want to write a file with no quotes and parentheses.

I tried using `",".join(map(str, key))`.

```
import csv
d={(1, 1, 1): 600, (5, 5, 5): 700, (4, 4, 4): 800}


with open("out.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key,items in d.items():
        w.writerow([key,items])
```

I get this:

```
"(1, 1, 1)",600
"(5, 5, 5)",700
"(4, 4, 4)",800
```

I expect this:

```
1, 1, 1, 600
5, 5, 5, 700
4, 4, 4, 800
```

Comment: If you try and write values containing commas into a comma-separated file, they have to be quoted so you can tell the commas that are part of the values from the commas that separate the values. If you want them to be separate values, don't join them all up as one value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unpack the key value to get it into list, i.e. (1,2,1) ->1,2,1 and pass this list to the `writerow` function.

In your present code, `[(1,1,1),600]` is going as feed and it is considering it as a 2-element list, hence producing the mentioned output.

You need to unpack the key value, i.e. `[(1,1,1),600]` to `[1,1,1,600]`.

This can be achieved by using the `*` operator,  `[*(1,1,1),600]`.

Also `open` with `w` mode not `wb` binary mode, as you are providing the data in ASCII format not in binary format.

```
import csv
d={(1, 1, 1): 600, (5, 5, 5): 700, (4, 4, 4): 800}


with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key,items in d.items():
        w.writerow([*key,items])
```

Otherwise, you can use this (if you do not want to unpack with `*`).

```
import csv
d={(1, 1, 1): 600, (5, 5, 5): 700, (4, 4, 4): 800}


with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key,items in d.items():
        lis = [i for i in key]+[items]
        w.writerow(lis)
```

Comment: Thanks , With what version of Python ? Cuz I does not work , please help !

Comment: i am using python 3.6